# Issue with ParallaxScroll ( from nirhart ) in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been looking for an easy to implement Parallax animation, although I've seen chrisjenx alternative, nirhart's is more the thing im looking for.

My problem is that I download [the repository](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll) , then use Import on eclipse and it doesn't work. This is the list of errors:

[image]

I re-downloaded the ADT from the official webpage and updated it. I'm compiling with SDK API 16 ( Android JB )

I'm kinda new to android, but I guess its throwing error for things like these

```
<com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.nirhart.parallaxscrollexample"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:parallax_factor="1.9"                           <-------------------------
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

I would live some help, thank you!

Comment: This project uses [API level 19](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll/blob/master/ParallaxScroll/project.properties) - have you got that installed?

Comment: Yes, i have API 16 and 19 installed. I've tried targeting each of them and the problem persists

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm a noob :P I imported the ''example'' thinking the library was already there. I had to import both proyects, the example and the original library. Having worked with java for a long time makes me feel like a proyect has no relation to others.. Thanks for the help!